# AWS EC2のインスタンスのRegionを変更したのですが、新しいRegionインスタンスがIPアドレスやDNSから閲覧できません。

Tags: aws, wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

AWS EC2 でU.S. VirginiaからEU FrankfurtにRegionを変えてスナップショット、AMIでインスタンスを移動させました。
ですが、新しいEU Frankfurtのインスタンスは、Public DNSやIPv4 Public IPでブラウザにアクセスしてもサイトが表示されません。
古い移行前のインスタンスを停止していないからでしょうか？
WordPress（bitnami）のインスタンスなのですが、管理画面も同様にアクセスできず、困っています。

Elastic IPsからEIPの関連付けを行う必要があるかと思ったのですが、元のU.S.VirginiaのインスタンスにはEIPを関連づけていないので、Elastic IPsからのEIP関連付けが上記の問題の解決策ではないような気もしています。

数日後にはretirementされる通知が来ているので、どうにかしたいのですが、どなたかご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 新しいEU Frankfurtのインスタンスにはセキュリティグループは設定されていますか？

Comment: take88さん、お返事をくださりありがとうございます。launch-wizard2が設定されていますね。

Answer (score 0):

セキュリティグループにインバウンドルールを追加するとアクセスできると思います。
U.S. Virginia で設定していたものと同等の設定をEU Frankfurtに追加してください。
追加したセキュリティグループをEC2インスタンスに割り当てると反映されます。

Comment: take88さん、アドバイスいただいた通りに設定しましたところ、無事に反映され、問題が解決しました。ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。